# Django 'GET' request error 500 strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Tags: django

My django API needs to handle from partners  'POST' and 'GET' request. Everything is fine when partners server sends 'POST' but when on 'GET' i've got an error.
Here is what i found in Chrome Network inspektor

```
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: someadress:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

i've tested 'GET' by Postman and it works fine, i've installed and setup `django-cors-headers`.
P.S. On sandbox partners server it worked fine, but on live i've got this error.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you want you can decorate your function with "@csrf_exempt" to avoid csrf checks or you can add their ip to whitelist

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added it in your origins in CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS.
Refer to this properly once https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/.